# WorkManager: FutureCallback always returns success no matter what result

Tags: rx-java, android-workmanager, android-guava

I am doing this:

```
val fileUploadRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<FileUploadWorker>().build()

Futures.addCallback(workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(this::class.simpleName!!, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, fileUploadRequest).result,
    object : FutureCallback<Operation.State.SUCCESS> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: Operation.State.SUCCESS?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: ")
        }

        override fun onFailure(t: Throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ")
        }
    },
    executor
)
```

with this RxWorker code:

```
override fun createWork(): Single<Result> {
        return Single.just(Result.failure())
}
```

I always end up in onSuccess(). How come?

Also: Is the Futures callback ever removed? Or does it live forever? Do I need to remove it manually during some circumstances?

Comment: Where is `createWork` even invoked?

Comment: By WorkManager. It's an overriden method in the RxWorker class.

Comment: Please provide the source code of `WorkManager` and `RxWorker`.

Comment: WorkManager is an Android API:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: I don't see any reason for it not to work. If you do a non-Rx version, does that invoke onFailure properly for you? Also if you delayed the failure result by 1 second, does that work?

Comment: I abandoned this solution in favor of livedata where I could get it to work.